# How to create new String value in Java JDI?

Tags: java, debugging, jvmti, jdi

I'd like to invoke a method in JDI which has `String` as a parameter. So first I will have to create a `String` value(`com.sun.jdi.Value`) but the only way which comes to my mind is to use the `newInstance()` method on `ClassType`, but this method also takes `Value` as parameter just like the `invokeMethod()` which I wanted to call in the first place. So I still need a `com.sun.jdi.Value` to create a `String`.... But how can I create the String without any `com.sun.jdi.Value`?

Comment: Are you looking for [`mirrorOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/VirtualMachine.html#mirrorOf(java.lang.String))?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, yes, that works. Thank you very much!